# AngularJS gets 401 (Unauthorized) on POST, but not Postman

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

Writing an AngularJS app. On POST, it gets a 401 error. Postman does not.

This is after a trail of hunting down a CORS issue that existed with AngularJS but not Postman.

My AngularJS POST looks like this:

```
function(resetRequest) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: baseUrl,
                data: resetRequest,
                params: {

                }
            })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
```

I have made the following changes to my ASP.Net web API in an attempt to resolve my POST CORS issues:

In Startup.cs:

```
var corsPolicy = new CorsPolicy
{
    AllowAnyMethod = true,
    AllowAnyHeader = true
};

var origins = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cors-orgins-local"];

if(origins != null)
{
    foreach(var origin in origins.Split(','))
    {
        corsPolicy.Origins.Add(origin);
    }
}
else
{
    //TODO: Throw exception
}

corsPolicy.SupportsCredentials = true;

var corsOptions = new CorsOptions
{
    PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
    {
        PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(corsPolicy)
    }
};



app.UseCors(corsOptions);
```

In IdentiyConfig.cs, in Create(..):

```
var origins = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cors-orgins-local"].Split(',');

context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] {origins[0]});
context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", new[] {"true"});
```

These changes have removed the CORS errors from appearing in the browser console on POST, which had to do with the origins, and the headers about origin and credentials.

How can I resolve this 401 error?

Comment: Have you added any authentication (ex: in headers..)that you are not sending?

Comment: @riteshmeher Not implicitly, unless there's some automatic authorization with AngularJS/ASP.Net that I'm unaware of. I'm certainly not passing any authorization with Postman.